# Passing item in another workspace in oracle apex using link

Tags: javascript, oracle, url, oracle-apex, apex

I am using below URL to pass value value from one workspace to another. The passed value show in URL but does not map on Item.

```
f?p=app_id:page_num:&APP_SESSION.&c=workspace_name::::item_name:&value.
```

Comment: From one workspace to another? You're passing values between **applications**, not workspaces. If you do it correctly, it *works*.

Comment: 2 different application and different workspace. passed value show in URL link but not in item.

Comment: *not shown in item* - please provide some more information. Does this item belong to a form ? Are you sure the item is not set *after* the value is passed from the url ? What is the behaviour you are observing ? Most important question.. if you run the page in debug - does that show any info that might guide you towards a solution ?

Comment: You're certainly not going to have any meaning with the sharing of APP_SESSION. I'd suggest you're being prompted to log in during this process, which is potentially why the value is being lost to a different session.

Comment: thankyou for your help. I modified the link and its working now.